# How to Override NyroModal Wrapper?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, nyromodal

How can I Override NyroModal Wrapper.

I dont want to override the css class, we need the ability TO ADD our divs instead of the native WRAPPER div.

On [GitHub](https://github.com/nyroDev/nyroModal/blob/master/js/jquery.nyroModal.filters.gallery.js) i found 2 functions: `beforeShowCont` and `filledContent`, but i dont know how to override the wrapper using these functions.

And I also found this article on [code google](http://code.google.com/p/nyromodal/issues/detail?id=509), and this is exactly what i want to develop, but it doesnt say how.

```
<table class="ctools-modal-content">
  <tr>
    <td class="popups-tl popups-border"></td>
    <td class="popups-t popups-border"></td>
    <td class="popups-tr popups-border"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="popups-cl popups-border"></td>
    <td class="popups-c">
      <div class="popups-container">
        <div class="popups-title">
          <span id="modal-title" class="modal-title"></span>
          <span class="popups-close"><a class="close" href="#">Close</a></span>
          <div class="clear-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="modal-content" class="modal-content">HERE WOULD .wrapper OR #nyroModalContent GO</div>
        <div class="popups-buttons"></div>
        <div class="popups-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="popups-cr popups-border"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="popups-bl popups-border"></td>
    <td class="popups-b popups-border"></td>
    <td class="popups-br popups-border"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've found [something](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8141170/1581050), i hope it help's.

Comment: I added new description; The resize is not a problem; I need to add a contour to the native nyro modal iframe

Comment: @Barnee what if there are multiple nyroModals on the screen? What you do with the stacked ones? How do you address those?

Answer (score 0):

I refer the nyroModal code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/nyromodal/issues/detail?id=168)

If you want to override the wrapper class of it, you can do it by following way.

- select the main container of the nyroModal.
- add the new style for its wrapper.

  i.e.

  div#nyroModalFull div.wrapper{ /* your own style*/ }
- load your own stylesheet after the nyroModal style

I hope this will work for you

Comment: Your answers tells us how TO override the class, we need the ability TO ADD our divs instead of the native WRAPPER div. ty anyway

Comment: you can do that by help of jQuery. i.e. $('div#nyroModalFull').find('div.wrapper').removeClass('div.wrapper').addClass('yourclassname');

Comment: OP asked how to override the wrapper DIV, and not the class.

Comment: we dont want to override the css style; we need to add new divs before the iframe